# converting text to 1 number in R, and converting NA to )

Tags: r, character, numeric

I'm quite new in R. My question is how can I change all text data in my csv file to 1 number, and changing those are character NA to 0 number.Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `as.integer(!is.na(yourdata$column))` or for the whole data `+(!is.na(yourdata))`

Comment: Please update your post by `edit`ing with the `dput` of small `head` of yourdata

Comment: I want forexample convert a sentence in a cell to number 1 and and those are NA to look 0, I tried the command you recommended but it doesn't change the dataset itself.Thanks for your help

Comment: You need to assign i.e. `yourdata[] <-  +(!is.na(yourdata))` for changing the orignal object

Comment: Could you explain more please? I tried that, eve, I tried replace but still I'm struggling

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that all data in your CSV file is text, and the NA are represented as text as well, this code should work:

```
df <- data.frame(c("hello", "hi", "NA", "hello"), 
                 c("NA", "hi", "NA", "hello"),
                 c("hello", "NA", "NA", "hello"))


ifelse(df == "NA", 0, 1)
```

For example, if you want to change the original CSV, you could use:

```
df <- read.csv(filepath)
df2 <- ifelse(df == "NA", 0, 1)
write.csv(df2, filepath)
```

This will NOT work if there is non-text data in your CSV as well.

Comment: I really appreciate your help:)